# requirejs load script progress

Tags: requirejs

Risking of asking a stupid question I will give it a try though.

Is it possible to display a progress indicator while RequireJs is loading dependencies?

For example:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {

    // Well, jQuery loaded in quite some time due to a low-speed connection
    //
    // Or maybe I wanted to show an overlay to prevent user of clicking on UI widgets until the load is complete
});
```

I don't want to start modifying the RequireJS source if there's some plugin out there which didn't show up in my Google searches.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. RequrieJs loads the module by creating a new script tag in the DOM and listens to the load event. There are no update events in between start and end loading. So it's not a limitation of requireJs but the DOM.

Comment: @explunit: If you have something to add, comment on this answer. Do not edit the answer.

Comment: If you inspect the html head area in Firebug or Chrome dev tools you can see what RequireJs does with the script tags and understand why it's not possible to have a progress indicator.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It made think of a better approach - instead of relying on 'script loaded' event I will implement this in the application logic.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to display a spinner or progress indicator, but not the bar itself. I could get status of requirejs (currently loading or idle), but not the % of loaded/needed to be loaded modules, because their dependencies are parsed upon every module load, but not at the beginning.

But, anyway, page with, at least, a simple spinner, is much better, than just blank page, while user waits.

No changes to requirejs needed! So..

Assume we have file require.conf.js with

```
require.config({...})
require(["app"], function () { 

// main entry point to your hugde app's code 
});
```

and it is loaded by html using

```
<script data-main="require.conf" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

This is standard requirejs scenario. Let's add the indicator to the

```
<div id="requirejs-loading-panel">
    <div id="requirejs-loading-status"></div>
    <div id="requirejs-loading-module-name"></div>
</div>
```

Ok, let's catch up requirejs's function called require.onResourceLoad and do all the magic needed. It will be called by requirejs upon every module load, passing the requirejs's context with dep tree and all other staff. We will use context to find out, whether requirejs is loading something or not. I did it in scheduled timer call, because onResourceLoad() is called only while loading, not when it is done loading. This code needs to be added to require.js.conf:

```
require.onResourceLoad = function (context, map, depMaps) {


    var loadingStatusEl = document.getElementById('requirejs-loading-status'),
        loadingModuleNameEl = document.getElementById('requirejs-loading-module-name');
    var panel = document.getElementById('requirejs-loading-panel');

    if (loadingStatusEl && loadingModuleNameEl) {


        if (!context) { // we well call onResourceLoad(false) by ourselves when requirejs is not loading anything => hide the indicator and exit

            panel.style.display = "none";
            return;
        }

        panel.style.display = ""; // show indicator when any module is loaded and shedule requirejs status (loading/idle) check
        clearTimeout(panel.ttimer); 
        panel.ttimer = setTimeout(function () {


            var context = require.s.contexts._;
            var inited = true;
            for (name in context.registry) {
                var m = context.registry[name];

                if (m.inited !== true) {
                    inited = false;
                    break;
                }

            } // here the "inited" variable will be true, if requirejs is "idle", false if "loading"

            if (inited) {
                require.onResourceLoad(false);  // will fire if module loads in 400ms. TODO: reset this timer for slow module loading
            }

        }, 400)
        if (map && map.name) { // we will add one dot ('.') and a currently loaded module name to the indicator

            loadingStatusEl.innerHTML = loadingStatusEl.innerHTML += '.'; //add one more dot character
            loadingModuleNameEl.innerHTML = map.name + (map.url ? ' at ' + map.url : '');
        }
    } else {


    }


};
```

One problem is: we cannot somehow figure out how much modules are needed to load, so we can't compute the actual % of loading progress. But, at least, we can find out, whether we're loading something or not (and event get currently loading module name) and show it to a nervous user

Comment: Thanks. I would have used this a while ago and maybe I'll use it for future development.

Comment: There is a mistake here i think: if (inited !== true)  should be m.inited !== true. Why do you even need m otherwise?

Comment: Another thing is: let's consider the case when last module loads and last timer is set. What if module is still loading after 400ms? Then we never get require.onResourceLoad(false) fired.

Comment: I extracted the timeout into a function "resetLoading" and added an ELSE {setTimeout(resetLoading, 100); } at the end.

Comment: Thanks!
Anyway, see the latest features of requirejs to create this loading indicator more easy

Answer (score 11):

Since v. 2.1.19 RequireJS has `onNodeCreated` config property. If you assign a function to it, that function will be called each time a `<script>` element is appended to a document to load a module.

The function will be provided with `node`, `config`, `moduleName`, and `url` arguments. By attaching event listeners to the `node`, you can detect when the script has been loaded or failed to be loaded.

Now you can detect when loading process starts and stops and can use that information to notify users:

```js
require.config({
  /* ... paths, shims, etc. */
  onNodeCreated: function(node, config, moduleName, url) {
    console.log('module ' + moduleName + ' is about to be loaded');

    node.addEventListener('load', function() {
      console.log('module ' + moduleName + ' has been loaded');
    });

    node.addEventListener('error', function() {
      console.log('module ' + moduleName + ' could not be loaded');
    });
  },
});
```

For IE < 9 you'd need additional code to attach event listeners.

**Note:** this only works for modules requested by RequireJS directly. Plugins (requirejs/text and such) each use their own loading mechanism and do not trigger `onNodeCreated`. Some trigger `onXhr` and `onXhrComplete` though, so you can handle them too:

```js
require.config({
  /* ... paths, shims, etc. */
  config: {
    text: {
      onXhr: function(xhr, url) {
        console.log('file ' + url + ' is about to be loaded');
      },
      onXhrComplete: function(xhr, url) {
        console.log('file ' + url + ' has been loaded');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @keleran. It seems the functionality was added to support [Subresource Integrity](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-subresource-integrity/) (according to https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1361)