# How to update loader when requireJS loads JS files from server

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have an application which is made using requireJS. It uses lot of JS files and takes time to download all. So I am thinking of providing progress bar while requireJS loads the JS files. I wanted to know if requireJS provides any hook or callback for each file load so that i can update progressbar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581563/requirejs-load-script-progress