# How can I get the progress of a downloading <script>?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say, for example, I'm creating a game. I have a small script whose job is to load all the assets and present a progress bar to the user while the assets load.

One such asset is a rather large script which contains the game logic. Perhaps upwards of 3 MB.

How can I show the loading progress of the second script to the user?

Comment: Closely related: [requirejs load script progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581563/requirejs-load-script-progress) ("*RequrieJs loads the module by creating a new script tag in the DOM and listens to the load event. There are no update events in between start and end loading.*")

Comment: That's a browser thing, not in our control as programmers. Only when the browser finish loading and "compiling" the JS file you can access it so the only way I can see is using several smaller files and splitting the logic among them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`<script>` tags only fire `load` and `error` events; they do not fire `progress` events. However, in modern browsers, [Ajax requests *do* support `progress` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress). You can load your script content and monitor progress through Ajax, and then place the script contents into a new `<script>` element when the load completes:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

// report progress events
req.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = event.loaded / event.total;
        // ...
    } else {
        // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
    }
}, false);

// load responseText into a new script element
req.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    var e = event.target;
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.innerHTML = e.responseText;
    // or: s[s.innerText!=undefined?"innerText":"textContent"] = e.responseText
    document.documentElement.appendChild(s);

    s.addEventListener("load", function() {
        // this runs after the new script has been executed...
    });
}, false);

req.open("GET", "foo.js");
req.send();
```

For older browsers that don't support Ajax `progress`, you can build your progress-reporting UI to show a loading bar only after the first `progress` event (or otherwise, show a generic spinner if no `progress` events ever fire).

Comment: Thanks for the code. But what if the script is for a third-party library?

Answer (score 2):

You might like to have a look at [How to show loading status in percentage for ajax response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690740/how-to-show-loading-status-in-percentage-for-ajax-response)

It is to see the status of an AJAX download. Since you are loading a script, it might not be the best way to get the file but it could work. You would then need to put the content received by the ajax call somewhere to execute, and eval is not recommended.

Comment: This seems like an acceptable use case for `eval`. Do you have an actual reason for not recommending it, or are you just saying that mindlessly?

Comment: `eval` was made for doing stuff like this. The only times `eval` is not recommended is when it isn't needed, or it's a big security risk. The only way this could be a security risk would be a man-in-the-middle attack or a compromised server - both of which provide way greater risks than `eval`.

Comment: I always been told to not use eval unless you REALLY need to... So you might be right. Maybe a script tag injection could be done too, just like requireJS does, they have to have a reason for not using eval?

Comment: Yes, this is a perfectly acceptable use case for eval. There is no user input anywhere - Only programmer input which you can trust :) ... Unless you don't trust yourself :p