# Get progress while importing bundle dynamicaly with import() and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, progress-bar

I'm coding an online game that loads levels dynamically with the following line:

```
import('/path/level.js')
.catch((error) => { reject(error); })
.then((data) => {
  // Display the new level
  // ...
}
```

This is a single page application, and the levels are loaded dynamically. The levels are heavy Webpack bundles. I would like to display a progress bar during the import.

Is there a way to get the status of the import ? Like a percentage or a number of bytes loaded?

Comment: See also ["How to display a progress bar while loading single bundled javascript file by webpack?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35195543/15261914)

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no built in function to achieve this approach, but at least you can show a loading until your component load or show a percentage bar and increase it randomly and when component loaded set the percentage bar to `100%`.
see this package, it may also be helpful https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable