# Is it possible to let webpacks System.import use ajax (for progress events)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, progress-bar, webpack, webpack-2

So I've just updated to webpack 2 and have my first working setup where webpack automatically creates chunks by looking at System.import calls. Pretty sweet!

However, I load the initial chunk with an ajax call so that I can [show the progress while loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126789/977206)

So my question is, can I overwrite or change the function of System.import somehow so that it will use an ajax request that I can listen to for events, instead of loading the chunk with a `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. webpack 2 translates `System.import()` to ordinary `require.ensure()` calls which just uses the `<script>` tag. Even the official [WHATWG Loader Spec](https://github.com/whatwg/loader) does not provide an API for this kind of event. I've [created an issue](https://github.com/whatwg/loader/issues/143) for this question.

Regarding webpack: There is a way to implement your own `require.ensure()`. However, since chunk loading is an integral part of webpack, this requires to dive a little deeper. I'm not sure how important this is for you, but you might be interested how things work inside webpack, so let's take a look:

In webpack, all internal features are implemented as plugins. This way, webpack is able to support a lot of different features and environments. So, if you're interested how things are implemented in webpack, it's always a good idea to a) take a look at [`WebpackOptionsApply`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js) or b) search for a specific string/code snippet.

Chunk loading depends heavily on the given [`target`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target), because you need different implementations for each environment. Webpack allows you to define custom targets. When you pass in a function instead of a string, webpack invokes the function with a `compiler` instance. There you can apply all the required plugins. Since our custom target is almost like the `web` target, we just copy all the stuff from the `web` target:

```
// webpack.config.js

const NodeSourcePlugin = require("webpack/lib/node/NodeSourcePlugin");
const FunctionModulePlugin = require("webpack/lib/FunctionModulePlugin");
const LoaderTargetPlugin = require("webpack/lib/LoaderTargetPlugin");
const JsonpChunkTemplatePlugin = require("webpack/lib/JsonpChunkTemplatePlugin");
const JsonpHotUpdateChunkTemplatePlugin = require("webpack/lib/JsonpHotUpdateChunkTemplatePlugin");

function customTarget(compiler) {
    compiler.apply(
        new JsonpTemplatePlugin(compiler.options.output),
        new FunctionModulePlugin(compiler.options.output),
        new NodeSourcePlugin(compiler.options.node),
        new LoaderTargetPlugin("web")
    );
}

module.exports = {
    entry:  require.resolve("./app/main.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    target: customTarget
};
```

If you take a look at each plugin, you will recognize that the `JsonpTemplatePlugin` is responsible for loading chunks. So let's replace that with out own implementation. We call it the `XHRTemplatePlugin`:

```
function customTarget(compiler) {
    compiler.apply(
        new XHRTemplatePlugin(compiler.options.output),
        new FunctionModulePlugin(compiler.options.output),
        new NodeSourcePlugin(compiler.options.node),
        new LoaderTargetPlugin("my-custom-target")
    );
}
```

Our `XHRTemplatePlugin` is responsible for providing the code in the main chunk, in each child chunk and for hot updates:

```
function XHRTemplatePlugin() {}

XHRTemplatePlugin.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {
    compiler.plugin("this-compilation", function(compilation) {
        compilation.mainTemplate.apply(new XHRMainTemplatePlugin());
        compilation.chunkTemplate.apply(new XHRChunkTemplatePlugin());
        compilation.hotUpdateChunkTemplate.apply(new XHRHotUpdateChunkTemplatePlugin());
    });
};
```

Maybe, you can also re-use the `JsonpChunkTemplatePlugin` and `JsonpHotUpdateChunkTemplatePlugin` plugin, but this depends on your use-case/implementation.

Your `XHRMainTemplatePlugin` now may look like this:

```
function XHRMainTemplatePlugin() {}

XHRMainTemplatePlugin.prototype.apply = function (mainTemplate) {
    mainTemplate.plugin("require-ensure", function(_, chunk, hash) {
        return this.asString([
            // Add your custom implementation here
            "fetch()"
        ]);
    });
};
```

I won't go any further here because I think this answer is already long enough. But I recommend to create a real small example project and to check the output created by webpack. The internal webpack plugins may look a little bit scary on first sight, but most of them are real short and do just one thing. You can also get some inspiration from them.

Comment: thank you so much. I've created a small webpack plugin before, and this is just perfect to get me - or anyone else -  started to implement this. I need to check with my employer/client if he wants the progress bar this bad, but either way I'll be coming back here when doing anything related to webpack plugins. Thank you for the effort and the very clear answer

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that this answer provides more insight to webpack internals for other developers. If you publish your plugin, let me know.

Regarding your client: IMHO there is too much technical overhead to implement your own chunk loading compared to the benefits. You could also use a spinner which does not need progress events.