# Angular 2 Initial loading progress

Tags: angular

I've tried my best to bring the bundle size of Angular 2 down and have been relatively successful in reducing the size to ~300kb (Angular 2 + jquery + bootstrap + some other small third party libraries) using `Browserify`+`Rollup`+`Minify`+`GZIP` but even with this size, it still takes a while to download the bundle and then there's the initial loading time for reflect and zone.js to take into consideration, meaning it can take up to 4-5 seconds on slower devices (mobile phones) to load up the site.

Whilst I understand that this is unavoidable (for now at least), is there a way to show the loading progress for the initial load in terms of percentage of download + reflect/zone.js initialization?

Most of the examples out there are like this:

```
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

Which is working and the `Loading...` can be replaced by a spinner or whatever custom template one might choose but is there any way to get the actual progress in a meaningful way?

What I'm looking for is something like `Gmail`'s loading progress which is an actual progress bar with min/max and not some indeterminate spinner so that users can have some form of indication as to how long they will need to wait for the site to load.

Many thanks in advance,

**Update (24-Oct-2016)**

I have started using `NGC` for ahead-of-time compiling (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) which has sped things up quite a bit (albeit bundle size has increased to ~500kb zipped) but it still takes ~300ms to load the website after everything has been downloaded.

Ideally, I would like to be able to intercept both the download and the loading process, investigate their status (for instance, 230kb/500kb downloaded or 10% of module building complete) and then load a progress bar and a status bar that actually gives some indication to the user what exactly they're waiting for.

What I currently have is to load a minimum CSS for a progress bar, show it and then load all the angular things in order on the `onLoad` function and whilst it's a lot smoother than before, it's still not obvious how long the user will have to wait - be that half a second to a few seconds depending on the internet connection and the device's capabilities.

Comment: Good question, but i think a generic solution (you might be using rollup, someone else might use webpack etc) is tricky? Probably requires some help/api/hook in angular for it to work too.

Comment: have you tried AOT compilation ? (for speed optimization)

Comment: @redaigbaria I have. It's definitely faster but still would rather have a progress bar with meaningful status for the 2 second or so it takes on slower devices.

Comment: Looks like you'd have to load scripts manually to be able to show actual progress: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126789/2706426

Comment: Have you tried SSR (server side rendering)?

Comment: Exactly suffering from the same issue. Was expecting good answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `reflect/zone.js`, but for download we can follow this

```html
    <body onload="showApp()">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="loadingContainer"></div>
        <my-app style="display: none"><my-app>
    </body>
```

```js
    showApp() {
        document.getElementById('loadingContainer').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByTagName('my-app')[0].style.display = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a second script in your `index.html`, which would then load all your other files (just as the `index.html` is doing now). 
Then you'd have a bunch of AJAX requests for your files and could add them to the DOM. To track the progress, you could try to use an HTTP HEAD request with the `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other things that you can do to reduce the loading time of the static resources.

- Try a hosting solution supported by CDN such as firebase hosting - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting
- Make your app a progressive web app. Progressive web apps uses service workers to cache the static resources inside user's device, so they needs to be update only when a new version of your application has been released - https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

When you use bootstrap, bootstrap has the problem that it blocks the main rendering thread. Run lighthouse from the developer tools to see if this might be your issue.

You may well attempt to reduce it from the sources, or only use what you are actually need.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/contents/#bootstrap-source-code

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a way to write JS code to inspect the current status of other in-progress files being downloaded.  What I would recommend you do here is probably what Gmail does, it's just a fake progress bar.  It has a slow-ish left-to-right animation that you can see move. If you app loads before it goes all the way to the right... who cares, that makes it look fast!

However, never have the progress bar actually reach 100%, it should stop just short in case the site is being slow.  This way it will indicate that it's still loading even though you can't tell how much longer it will be.

Chrome does this exact thing with it's loading bar animation. If the page loads quick it just quickly completes the animation, if the page is being slow then it just slowly animates until you get to that last little bit and hangs there.

It's all a trick really, there have been interesting psychological studies on the perception of speed with different loading animations.  Check it out here: [Faster Progress Bars: Manipulating Perceived                 Duration with Visual Augmentations *(PDF)*](https://www.chrisharrison.net/projects/progressbars2/ProgressBarsHarrison.pdf)

See some CSS loading bar animation examples here: https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/progress-bar-css/