# How to set img.src in HTML from responseText in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44766402/12708425) answer & file downloading is successful. The facing problem is to set downloaded image file into the `img.src` tag.

**Image link:** https://images.pexels.com/photos/853199/pexels-photo-853199.jpeg?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&dl=aerial-view-of-seashore-near-large-grey-rocks-853199.jpg&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4000&w=6000

**Code:**

```
function onReadyState(e){

    let r = e.target;
    if(r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200){
        return
    }
    console.log(r)
    let img = document.getElementById('downloaded-img')
    let base64  = btoa(r.response)
    img.src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+base64
}
```

I tried to convert responseText into base64 to set `img.scr` for display downloaded image. But I got error,

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The
>   string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
>       at XMLHttpRequest.downloadCompleted

Then I used below code by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603875/12708425) answer.

```
   let base64  = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(r.responseText)))
```

The error is gone. But `img` is still whitespace. How can I resolve it? Thanks in advance...

**Update:** 
I used [this](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/93493/screenshots/1445193/notfound.png) link. It throws below error,

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/93493/screenshots/1445193/notfound.png'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I used [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gCA72TalLNU/VyZdUQ2AFCI/AAAAAAAAAFA/4fTrT4GaObMs2w1RO-11tMug3h8fec5AACLcB/s1600/Unloaded%2BPicture.JPG) link too, Didn't got any error But I got same blank area instead of image.

[image]

Comment: Does it at least show the icon for not-found images (something like [this](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/93493/screenshots/1445193/notfound.png))?

Comment: @RHShanks92, Throws error says `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/93493/screenshots/1445193/notfound.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: And [this one](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gCA72TalLNU/VyZdUQ2AFCI/AAAAAAAAAFA/4fTrT4GaObMs2w1RO-11tMug3h8fec5AACLcB/s1600/Unloaded%2BPicture.JPG)?

Comment: @RHShanks92, Yes, 2nd one loads data. But same blank area. I updated question with your links

Answer (score 3):

`btoa` receive a string as an argument, but you have a stream. You can use `URL.createObjectURL` for get a blob url

```js
const url = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/853199/pexels-photo-853199.jpeg?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&dl=aerial-view-of-seashore-near-large-grey-rocks-853199.jpg&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4000&w=6000';
const img = document.querySelector('img');

fetch(url).then(data => data.blob()).then(blob => {
    const src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.src = src;
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

```html
<img height="150"/>
```

For download an image from url:

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href='https://images.pexels.com/photos/853199/pexels-photo-853199.jpeg?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&dl=aerial-view-of-seashore-near-large-grey-rocks-853199.jpg&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4000&w=6000';
a.download='filname.jpg';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
a.remove()
```

Comment: I am using the concept for download image file using pure JS and set it to the img tag. I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44766402/12708425

Comment: for download you not need all this staff.. `var a = document.createElement('a');a.href='url';a.download='filname.jpg';document.body.appendChild(a);a.click();a.remove()`

Comment: sorry for misleading, I want to show progress for corresponding image download. That's why I used that code from the answer that I have attached in question.

Answer (score 0):

One long way is to use `FileReader` that assuming you received the data as blob
so this should work (hopefully) :

```
xml = new XMLHttpRequest()
xml.open("GET", "YOUR URL", true)
xml.responseType = "blob"
var blob
xml.onload = function(e){blob = xml.response;}
file = new FileReader()
var base64
file.onloadend = function() {base64 = file.result}
file.readAsDataURL(blob)
img = document.getElementById('downloaded-img')
img.src = base64
```

Comment: Only use Stack Snippets for code that's *actually runnable* - code that isn't runnable should not be given a button for people to Run, it just adds noise

Comment: really sorry, I am new and I am learning, thank you for taking the time to explain.