# how to show download progress on file download?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I have an api to download file. It is able to download file but showing only after download completes. there is no download progress.
I want when user hit that url it will show download progress in chrome, currently it is showing after completion.
I am using spring boot.

```
public responseEntity<Resource>getFile(String fileName){
    byte[] data=null;
    File file=new File(fileName);
    InputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(file);
    data=IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    ByteArrayResource fileToDownload = new ByteArrayResource(data);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .header("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName)
                .body(fileToDownload);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that the answer has nothing to do with the server side, and must be implemented client-side

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript in your webpage. This has nothing to do with how the server sends the file, and must be displayed client-side -- well, the server *could* output somewhere how far it is along *sending* the file, but that is not what you want to show - you are interested in showing how much you have *received*, and showing it in the client; so any answer will have to rely on JS+html to an extent. Why not solve it entirely in the client side?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390950/how-show-file-download-progress-using-javascript) they use the following code:

```
function saveOrOpenBlob(url, blobName) {
    var blob;
    var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlHTTP.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xmlHTTP.onload = function(e) {
        blob = new Blob([this.response]);   
    };
    xmlHTTP.onprogress = function(pr) {
        //pr.loaded - current state
        //pr.total  - max
    };
    xmlHTTP.onloadend = function(e){
        var fileName = blobName;
        var tempEl = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(tempEl);
        tempEl.style = "display: none";
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        tempEl.href = url;
        tempEl.download = fileName;
        tempEl.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
    xmlHTTP.send();
}
```

Note that you are missing part where you display the progress somewhere. For example, you could implement it as follows:

```
    xmlHTTP.onprogress = function(pr) {
        //pr.loaded - current state
        //pr.total  - max
        let percentage = (pr.loaded / pr.total) / 100;
        document.getElementById("progress").textContent = "" + percentage + "% complete";
    };
```

This assumes that there is something like

```
  <span id="progress">downloading...</span>
```

in your html